# Node JS video streaming wont end sending data

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, react-native-video

so I am building a mobile app on Expo and trying to play a video from my MongoDB using GFS. But I ran in to a problem that IOS is asking for a Range as a first request , so i found the way to rewrite my Node JS server to send Videos with Range. But it doesnt look like it solved my issue on IOS but now it also broke the WEB and Android. Does anyone know what can be the issue. My new Code is posted Under as well as

```
if(req.headers['range']){
        const range = req.headers.range;
        const total = file.length;
        const positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        const start = Number(positions[0]);
        const end = positions[1] ? Number(positions[1]) : total -1;
        console.log(start);
        console.log(end)
        console.log(positions)
        const chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
        
        const header={
          "Content-Range" : "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/"+ total,
          "Accept-Ranges" :"bytes",
          "Content-Length" : chunksize,
          "Content-Type": file.contentType
        }
        
        res.writeHead(206,header);
        const readstream = gfs.gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id,{ start: start, end: end });

        readstream.on("error", (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(404).json({
            err: "Error reading file",
          });
        });
        readstream.pipe(res);
      
      }else {
        const readstream = gfs.gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id);
        res.set("Content-Type", file.contentType);
        res.set("Content-Length" , file.length)
        //res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
        readstream.on("error", (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(404).json({
            err: "Error reading file",
          });
        });
        readstream.pipe(res);
      }
```

EXPO :

```
              <Video
              ref={video}
              style={styles.video}
              onLoadStart={() => setIsPreloading(true)}
              onReadyForDisplay={() => setIsPreloading(false)}
              onError={e => {
                console.log(e);
              }}
              source={{
                uri: tempVideo.url,
              }}
              useNativeControls
            />
```

The thing I dont understand is that the Bunny video works fine , but when it comes to my videos, it breaks.

Last Error on EXPO is : The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -1005 and domain "NSURLErrorDomain".

Answer (score 0):

I was missing plus one in:

```
const readstream = gfs.gridfsBucket.openDownloadStream(file._id, { start: start, end: end + 1 }); // was "end: end,"
```

Apparently this array's end is not -1 and since I subtracted -1 above for the range header it gave a partial content error.